# "Bad value " in exec.Command output

Tags: go, exec

My go language program prints "Bad value for option -n 1, valid range is from 1 to 4294967295." when trying to ping using below code snippet

```
result , err := exec.Command("ping","-n 1", "-w 1", ip).Output()
fmt.Printf("%s\n", result)
```

When doing it from cmd in Win i.e. 'ping -n 1 -w 1 8.8.8.8' is fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separate the `-n` and `-w` flags and their values into separate arguments (your shell was already doing this):

```
result , err := exec.Command("ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "1", ip).Output()
```

Answer (score 1):

`exec.Command()` doesn't create a string to run all at once.

It creates the `ping` process and a set of options that gets sent to it.

So each flag and its corresponding values need to be passed separately:

`result, err := exec.Command("ping","-n", "1", "-w", "1", ip).Output()`